# can rest framework like jersey be used in clojure instead of compojure

Tags: rest, frameworks, clojure, jersey, compojure

iam newbie to clojure, just curious as to can i use jersey REST api as REST webframework for clojure? all along i see people talking about compojure? if you can provide me any resource
or reasoning that would be great

Thank you

Comment: Is there some reason you would prefer to use jersey to compojure?

Comment: a) jersey is jsr standard hence more java libraries, portablility
b) i dont want html stuff on my severside, i just want to send a json to heavy client, say written in GWT.
c) i read annotations cannot be used, jersey uses all annotaions, probably there is non annotated way of doing things(i have yet to explore) annotations is like metadata , i still dont get why clojure dosent allow annotations (or i am a newbie so i may be ignorant)

Comment: oh I didn't know about the use of annotations. It's not so much that clojure doesn't allow annotations as they just haven't implemented them. I don't know if they ever will. Most of the time clojures syntax would fill the need that annotations fill in java code so it's probably just hasn't been something anyone needed.

If your worried about portability then why are you using clojure?

Comment: Annotations are coming to Clojure! See http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/d2128e1505c0c117

Answer (score 4):

You can use jersey just the same as you can use any other java library in clojure. As to whether jersey or compojure would be better for you needs it's hard to say. You would have to provide more details about what you want to do and how you want to do it.

I find compojure very good for doing Rest in in an ideomatically clojure way. If you are familiar with jersey though then it may be a better fit and get you up and running faster.